# Route incoming traffic on one port to a DHCP server running on the same device

Tags: networking, iptables, port-forwarding

I have the following setup:

- A computer with the Ubuntu OS that is on a network and has internet access. Let's call it PublicIP
- An isc DHCP server that is running with a subnet of 255.255.255.0 and an IP of 10.73.27.x
- A DVR that is connected to the internal network through the computer through the isc DHCP server. It's broadcasting an RTSP stream on let's call it LanIP Class A: 10.73.27.117, port 544.

My end goal is to set up a reverse tunnel through port 544 on the Ubuntu computer so that I can access the stream data being broadcast by the DVR at the LanIP. I'm attempting to forward all traffic from port 544 on the main computer to the DVR internally.

I've been banging my head trying to understand `iptables`, but I can't seem to get the right solution created. I attempted the following `iptables` rule:

```shell
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 544 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.73.27.117:544
```

but so far have had no success. In order to check this, I am essentially running a

```shell
telnet localhost 544
```

to verify that a connection is able to be created.

I'm able to

```shell
telnet 10.73.27.117 544
```

without any problem, but `localhost` gives an error:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: use bridge for broadcast packets.